# Unable to Run Odoo Service at Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-11

I am new to ubuntu but with the help of [this tutorial](https://linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/) , i am trying to run Odoo 11 from its source code .While i tried to run this command

```
sudo systemctl start odoo.service
```

And after that while i tried to check status of my service using command

```
sudo systemctl status odoo.service
```

then its replies in the Console

```
 odoo.service - Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/odoo.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-03-29 15:28:38 PKT; 7s ago
  Process: 4072 ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo-server.conf --addons-path=/opt/odoo/addons/ (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4072 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:     import odoo.tools as tools
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:     from . import pdf
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/pdf.py", line 4, in <module>
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]:     from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 odoo-server[4072]: ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 systemd[1]: odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 systemd[1]: odoo.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 29 15:28:38 hassan-Latitude-E6420 systemd[1]: odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But i had installed PyPDF2 Module already.

Comment: You could use the interactive python cli with `python<VERSION> -i` and try to import the packages. That way it should be possible to at least figure out if the packages are there and further if the service is using the correct python version.

Comment: Hello Hassan,

Here gives error is PyPDF2 is not installed. 
Fix this error for::  sudo -H pip3 install PyPDF2

Comment: Install using PIP3 or Python-3 other wise it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with my service . I haven't installed Python module using pip3 package manager.So that's why python base modules wasn't available. So i simply install pip3 using command

```
pip install python3-pip
```

And then again started my odoo service using command

```
sudo systemctl start odoo
```

Finally it started working like charm.